# for loop randomly crashing on certain iterations

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, for-loop, titanium

there must be someone out there who can spot my error! I'm parsing an xml feed and running through a loop to get certain items on the page:

```
www.highlandradio.com/feed/
```

I am encountering an error on the line where I am setting the variable mp3Test. All I want to do is to set it equal to the url attribute of the enclosure tag (if it exists). This is why I am including the test to check if each item has an enclosure tag, if it does I am setting it to be equal to the url tag but if it doesn't I am setting it to be equal to 'null.mp3' for now. When running through the loop I am getting the correct numbers for a certain amount and then on some iterations of the loop, i crashes. I am using titanium and so am not getting any proper error messages. It simply highlights the line where I set up mp3Test and says to debug the current instruction pointer. I'm going crazy with this. Please help.

```
var url="http://www.highlandradio.com/feed/"; 

var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.onload = function() {
    // Data is returned from the blog, start parsing
    var doc = this.responseXML.documentElement;    

    // begin looping through blog posts
    var items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

    var enclosure = doc.getElementsByTagName("enclosure");
    console.log("NEWEST Enclosure Length -----------"+enclosure.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {        

        var itemsEnclosureLength=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("enclosure").length;
        var itemsEnclosureExists=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("enclosure");
        console.log("EXISTs ----------------------------------"+ itemsEnclosureExists);
        console.log("Newest ENCLOSURE LENGTH ---------------------- [ "+i+ " ]" + itemsEnclosureLength);

        var str=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("content:encoded").item(0).text;
        console.log("STRING TEST "+ str);

        var patt1=/([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/i;

        var urlMatch = str.match(patt1);
        console.log("MATCHES TESTER -----------------------------------" + typeof urlMatch);

        data.push({

            title: items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text,            
            leftImage: str.match(patt1) !== null ? str.match(patt1)[0] : 'image_news.png',
            dataToPass: items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).text,
            mp3Test: itemsEnclosureLength > 0 ? items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("enclosure").item(i).getAttribute("url"):'NULL.MP3'
        });
        console.log("Check this --------------------------"+ mp3Test);



    }
```

**BUMP2**

Comment: `items.item(i)` should be `items[i]`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Barmar no. Not with Titanium. items.item(i) is working fine for all other tags. If I comment out the line with mp3Test, it will run. There's something I'm missing :(

Comment: @Barmar It can be, but technically, `.item()` is a real, valid method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection#Methods . I like `[i]` better though

Comment: @Ian I've tried [i] before and it caused the app to crash even on a basic iteration which just loops through and adds the title to an array each time.

Comment: Hey, 
Can you show your Response Data?
then, may be I can help you.

Comment: @MRT I'll work on getting you the log now. My device for testing is at work. I'll see if I can get another now

Comment: @MRT No I can't get my hands on a device. I can post the logs Monday morning. Hopefully you can help then?

Comment: Well if you have a problem between `[i]` and `.item(i)`, you have a more serious problem. They should be interchangeable: http://jsfiddle.net/bXzMU/

Comment: @Ian they are not interchangeable with titanium! I got it sorted. The second item(i) should have been item(0) i.e.               var itemsEnclosureExists=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("enclosure");
itemsEnclosureExists.item(0).getAttribute("url"); and set up an extra condition in my for loop

Comment: @user2363025 Very interesting, I shouldn't have assumed it would be fine! So you got it working then? You might want to post an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using two counters which had the same value! Silly mistake but...Here's the solution:

```
var itemsEnclosureLength=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("enclosure").length;
var itemsEnclosureExists=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("enclosure");

if (itemsEnclosureExists){ 

     for (n=0; n<itemsEnclosureLength; n++){
         mp3=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("enclosure").item(n).getAttribute("url");
     }
}
else{
     mp3= 'NULL.mp3';
}
```